# Angular FormControl minlength error not appearing in the errors object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to access the minlength error but when I log all the errors it isn't there.

This is my form control

```js
title: new FormControl("", [Validators.minLength(10), Validators.required]),
```

Here I'm expecting to see both the required and minlength error.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.data.get('title')?.errors)
}
```

but instead, I only see the required one.

[image: The console.log result]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If title value is empty then it will fire required when there is any value in title then only it will check for minLength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Angular Validators `minLength()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators),

> The minLength validator logic is also not invoked for values when
> their length property is 0 (for example in case of an empty string or
> an empty array), to support optional controls.
>
> You can use the standard required validator if empty values should not
> be considered valid.

Hence **`minLength` validator only fires when `title` is not an empty string.**